# R_ solve an equation for attack rate and reproduction number in epidemiology

Tags: r

I would like to estimate an attack rate (*AR*) (fraction of population that becomes infected) based on an estimated reproduction number (*R0*) (number of secondary cases produced by a single infective individual during the infectious period in a susceptible population).

*S=exp(-R0(1-S))*, with *S* the proportion of remaining susceptible people after the epidemic has burned out.

and assuming lifelong immunity after infection, *AR =  1-S.*

I have *R0* in a .csv table by MonthYear, city and would like to calculate *AR* for each MonthYear/city.

I tried:

```
library(rootSolve)
f<- function(y,x){Tab$AR=1-(y-exp(-x*(1-y)))}
x=Tab$R0
solve(f)
```

Error message:

```
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

Then I tried

```
R0.vec = Tab$R0 
AR.vec = numeric(length(R0.vec)) 

for(ii in 1:length(AR.vec)){   
AR.vec[ii] = 1 -optimize(f=function(S){(S-exp(-R0.vec[ii]*(1-S)))},interval=c(0,1))$minimum
    } 
AR.fun.vec = approxfun(R0.vec,AR.vec)
```

Error message:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Warning messages:
1: In optimize(f = function(S) { ... : NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
2: In optimize(f = function(S) { ... : NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
3: In optimize(f = function(S) { ... : NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
```

I would love any advice on this to get my *ARs*, as this is all new for me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Totally unclear what you are trying to do. No data, no reproducible code. In addition `solve` is **not** part of package `rootSolve`.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER thanks to Dr Karline Soetaert 
`

```
 Sfun <- function(x, R0) return(x - exp(-R0*(1-x)))
 require(rootSolve)
 R0vec <- R0

result <- rep(0,times=length(R0vec))
for (i in 1:length(R0vec))
 result[i] <- multiroot(f = Sfun, start = 0, positive = TRUE, R0 = 
         R0vec[i])$root

 AR <- 1-result

 Print(AR)`
```